# war deploy from IntelliJ to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, intellij-idea

I need to publish my web app on Heroku anche I use command line

`heroku war-deploy <war-file-path> --app <app-name>`

I use IntelliJ to export my war file. When I test file with my local Tomcat Server there are no problem.

On Heroku I have this error:
"Application error - An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

I think is only an IntelliJ problem

Comment: Take a look in your logs with `heroku logs`. It should have a hint why your application is crashing.

Comment: In log I can see only this type of error `2020-04-09T15:27:47.469467+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=##host## request_id=005d5a28-3d17-4614-bee9-2b7a6946bced fwd="131.175.25.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to your war file path. IntelliJ default name is ":war archive". Ensure your file path don't contain spaces or 
accented characters.
In my case solved the problem